# ToC (fig, tab, index, glossary & bib) each in a subsection beneath a Section called References

Tags: table-of-contents, tocbibind

How can I make `ToC`, `LoF`,`gls`, `idx` & `bib` lists as a subsection?

I use lualatex and [tocbibind package](http://www.pirbot.com/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tocbibind/tocbibind.pdf). But the bibliography does not show up in `ToC` as well as I would need to get the entries of all Lists in  subsections beneath the section:'References'. Is that possible?

edit: printscreens now showing all subsections numbered as wanted.
[image]
[image]
[image]

edit: [WIP](x = done)

- [x] Num LOT
- [x] Num LOF
- [x] Num BIB
- [x] Num GLS
- [x] List BIB as subsection
- [x] List GLS as subsection
- [ ] List LOT as subsection
- [ ] List LOF as subsection
- [ ] List IDX as subsection
- [ ] Num IDX

mwe edited:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage[
nottoc, % TOC in TOC as line with Pagenumber
numbib, % Number bib
numindex, % Number Idx
]{tocbibind} % add line to TOC with Fig,Tab,Ind,
\usepackage{tikz} %Support for more advanced Graphics
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{imakeidx} % Word Index
\makeindex[
intoc, % this adds the Index to TOC!
]
\usepackage[
toc,% this adds the Index to TOC!
section=subsection,
numberedsection
]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@online{wikipedia,
    title = {Wikipedia},
    month = {10},
    year = {2018},
    url = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\begin{filecontents}{glossary.tex}
\newglossaryentry{testing}{
    name={testing},
    description={t.b.d.},
    text={testing}
}
\end{filecontents}
\input{glossary}
\renewcommand{\listoftables}{\begingroup
    \tocsection
    \tocfile{\listtablename}{lot}
 \endgroup}
 \renewcommand{\listoffigures}{\begingroup
    \tocsection
    \tocfile{\listfigurename}{lot}
 \endgroup}
 \renewcommand{\listoffigures}{\begingroup
    \tocsection
    \tocfile{\listfigurename}{lot}
 \endgroup}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents 
\section{Section one}
  test (idx)\index{test}(reference)\ref{sample}(cite)\cite{wikipedia}(glossary)\gls{testing}
  \begin{figure}[!ht]
      \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}
      \caption{sample}
      \label{sample}
  \end{figure}
  \begin{table}[htp]
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.03\linewidth}}
      sample table
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
  \caption{default}
  \label{default}
  \end{table}
\section{Referenzen (German for References)}
  \printbibliography[heading=subbibnumbered]
  \listoffigures
  \listoftables
  \printindex
  \printglossaries[toclevel=subsection,numberedsection]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `tocbibind` can not take grip of all `toc` - like additions. It is meant by design initially for `toc`, `bib` and `ind`, (and `lof/lot`), but not for `gls` etc. With `biblatex` there is a special setup, as well for `glossaries`

Comment: and why does it not show `bib` in my case here?

Comment: As I wrote, `biblatex` needs a special setup...

Comment: ok i found that part.([heading=bibintoc]) I will add it to the mwe. still need to find out how to subsec the hole lists...

Comment: Yes, I meant that line... but why do you want the subsection level? That does not look nice

Comment: So you want the glossary to be subsection 2.4? Then use `section=subsection,numberedsection` in the `glossaries` package options.

Comment: `subbibintoc` for biblatex.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: But wouldn't `[section=subsection]` use a subsection title for the glossary itself as well, i.e. a small heading?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, but I was assuming that was what was required. It's a bit odd to have the heading appear as a section in the text but as a subsection in the toc, but perhaps I misread the question.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: It is odd regarding the request to insert the `ToC` - related entries below some level of `\listofsomething`, but perhaps this could be another option for `\printglossaries` to allow for section style heading but group it as subsection... e.g. `\printglossaries[toclevel=subsection,numberedsection]` etc...  I would personally not group the glossary/listof... entries as subsection, but in any way I prefer section titles for glossaries.

Comment: I think the `lualatex` reference is irrelevant here...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'm not keen on the idea of `toclevel` as it encourages inconsistency. The toc level ought to be the same level as the heading it refers to, but from the image I'm assuming that OP wants both toc and headings to be numbered subsections for all the list of... ("References indent and set number 2.1 before").

Comment: i added some more clear printscreens. Does this answer your questions?

Comment: got `\printbibliography[heading=subbibnumbered]` working like i need and `\printglossaries[toclevel=subsection,numberedsection]` also. So im now searching for the three last cases LOF,LOT,IDX.

Comment: i found how to list LOF,LOT with numbers but its only in section not subsection as i need. \renewcommand{\listoftables}{\begingroup
    \tocsection
    \tocfile{\listtablename}{lot}
 \endgroup}

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: Well, **I** don't object  your objection ;-) If users prefer having small glossary headings because they want to use subsection entries its their decision.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion without package `tocbibind`: use `\indexsetup{level=\subsection` provided by package `imakeidx` and use package `tocbasic` to number LoF and LoT as subsections.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{tikz}% loads also graphicx etc.

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\addtotoclist[float]{lof}
\renewcommand*\listoffigures{\listoftoc[{\listfigurename}]{lof}}
\setuptoc{lof}{numbered,leveldown}
\addtotoclist[float]{lot}
\renewcommand*\listoftables{\listoftoc[{\listtablename}]{lot}}
\setuptoc{lot}{numbered,leveldown}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[
  section=subsection,
  numberedsection
]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\indexsetup{
  level=\subsection,
  %noclearpage % does not work as expected, removes the index in this example??
}
\makeindex

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@online{wikipedia,
    title = {Wikipedia},
    month = {10},
    year = {2018},
    url = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\begin{filecontents}{glossary.tex}
\newglossaryentry{testing}{
    name={testing},
    description={t.b.d.},
    text={testing}
}
\end{filecontents}
\input{glossary}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents 
\section{Section one}
  test (idx)\index{test}(reference)\ref{sample}(cite)\cite{wikipedia}(glossary)\gls{testing}
  \begin{figure}[!ht]
      \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}
      \caption{sample}
      \label{sample}
  \end{figure}
  \begin{table}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c}
      sample table
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{default}
    \label{default}
  \end{table}
\section{Referenzen (German for References)}
  \printbibliography[heading=subbibnumbered]
  \listoffigures
  \listoftables
  \printindex
  \printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I added a manual line to toc.

its not properly aligned but it fakes the missing subsectioning of those packages (not nice) but effectively.

Its sad that those packages do not work better together.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage[
nottoc, % TOC in TOC as line with Pagenumber
numbib, % Number bib
numindex, % Number Idx
notlot,
notlof,
]{tocbibind} % add line to TOC with Fig,Tab,Ind,
\usepackage{tikz} %Support for more advanced Graphics
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{imakeidx} % Word Index
\makeindex[
%intoc, % this adds the Index to TOC!
]
\usepackage[
toc,% this adds the Index to TOC!
section=subsection,
numberedsection
]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@online{wikipedia,
    title = {Wikipedia},
    month = {10},
    year = {2018},
    url = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\begin{filecontents}{glossary.tex}
\newglossaryentry{testing}{
    name={testing},
    description={t.b.d.},
    text={testing}
}
\end{filecontents}
\input{glossary}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents 
\section{Section one}
  test (idx)\index{test}(reference)\ref{sample}(cite)\cite{wikipedia}(glossary)\gls{testing}
  \begin{figure}[!ht]
      \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}
      \caption{sample}
      \label{sample}
  \end{figure}
  \begin{table}[htp]
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.03\linewidth}}
      sample table
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
  \caption{default}
  \label{default}
  \end{table}
\section{Referenzen}
  %\nocite{*}      %------------ BIBLIOGRAPHY --------------
  \printbibliography[heading=subbibnumbered]
  \stepcounter{subsection}
  \newpage       %---------------- FIGURES -----------------
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{
    \protect\numberline{\thesubsection} Abbildungsverzeichniss}
  \listoffigures
  \stepcounter{subsection}
  %\newpage        %-------------- TABLES ------------------
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{
    \protect\numberline{\thesubsection} Tabellenverzeichniss}
  \listoftables
  \stepcounter{subsection}
  %\newpage        %--------------- INDEX ------------------
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{
    \protect\numberline{\thesubsection} Index}
  \printindex
  %\newpage        %-------------- GLOSSARY ----------------
  \printglossaries[toclevel=subsection,numberedsection]
\end{document}
```

[image]